# Store output from command in variable in Bash. The output is being run instead of stored

Tags: bash

I am trying to store the output from a command in Bash in a variable, but instead of storing the output it is being interpreted as a command and run. That is not what I want.

`tmp="$($line | awk '{print $1}')"`  This runs the output from `awk` as a command.

`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`  This prints out the output I want to store in the variable.

How can I get the output from the second line stored in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
tmp=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
```

But that's a [Useless Use of Echo](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2012/12/useless-use-of-echo.html). Use a here-string instead:

```
tmp=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$line")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

var=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`

With the backticks